# Enabling a submit button through disabled checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

[GIF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmFg.gif)(In this GIF my checkboxes are disabled by default and auto check if i click the phase buttons) 
[GIF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrh35.gif)(In this GIF my first checkbox is enabled, and if the first checkbox is clicked the submit button works)
My end goal is to actually have the submit button work if they re automatically checked like in the first GIF.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>


</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="enableShadowButton()">Click me to submit Phase1</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1"/ disabled> Phase1
    <br>

    <button onclick="phase2Function()">Click me to submit Phase2</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2"/ disabled> Phase2
    <br>

    <button onclick="phase3Function()"> Click me to submit Phase3</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c3"/ disabled> Phase3
    <br>

    <button onclick="phase4Function()"> Click me to submit Phase4</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c4"/ disabled> Phase4
    <br>

    <button onclick="phase5Function()">  Click me to submit Phase5</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c5"/ disabled> Phase5
    <br>

    <button onclick="shadowFunction()" id="shadowbutton" disabled>Shadow Button</button>

<!--This script defines the functionalilty of the buttons which is 1.Autochecking and 2.Alerting-->
<script>


        function enableShadowButton() {
        document.getElementById("c1").checked=true;
        alert("You have completed Phase 1!");
        }
       function phase2Function() {
        document.getElementById("c2").checked=true;
        alert("You have completed Phase 2!");
        }
       function phase3Function() {
        document.getElementById("c3").checked=true;
        alert("You have completed Phase 3!");
        }
       function phase4Function() {
        document.getElementById("c4").checked=true;
        alert("You have completed Phase 4!");
        }
       function phase5Function() {
        document.getElementById("c5").checked=true;
            alert("You have completed Phase 5!");
            shadowFunction();
        }

//This function uses .checked(which makes sure the box is check marked) for 1-5 before moving on. Previously we used .checked=true which actually marks the boxes rather than verifying it

    function shadowFunction(){

           if((document.getElementById("c1").checked) &&
              (document.getElementById("c2").checked) &&
              (document.getElementById("c3").checked) &&
              (document.getElementById("c4").checked) &&
              (document.getElementById("c5").checked))
              { 
                   document.getElementById("shadowbutton").disabled=false;
                }

    }
</script>
<!--This script defines the functionalilty of the buttons which is 1.Autochecking and 2.Alerting-->




<!--best practice is to put script at the bottom of body so the page loads first, if in between head page wont load along with script-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

<!--<li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>-->





[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmFg.gif
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrh35.gif
```

Comment: That's nice, maybe come back some other time with a question.

Comment: @Gon Senpai Your Shadow button is not disabled initially

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the functionality of shadowFunction() in phase1Function(). If the button is disabled the if statement in shadowFunction() never runs.

Comment: you are a god @TacoWilson, ive been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours, THANKS!

Comment: Okay so now i have a new problem, whenever I click my phase 5 button it auto checks checkboxes 1,2 and 3, but what i really want it to do is verify that these 3 boxes were checked not to actually check these 3 boxes.

Comment: I updated the original post, please refer to the shadowFunction() and phase5Function() portions. Thanks!

Comment: In your if statement you're setting the the values of the check boxes not checking whether or no they're checked. get rid of the "=true." To return the value of the checkbox use "document.getElementById("c5").checked"

Comment: Let me get this straight, what you're telling me is "document.getElementById("c5").checked"  would tell me whether or not the box is checked.
What I want is my if statement checks that boxes 1, 2 and 3 are actually checked which is why we set the if statement with = true. which concluded as why I am trying to figure out a verification to verifiy if the student have completed their phases. sorry for the poor english, i am from learning American Language.

Comment: Yeah "document.getElementById("c5").checked" returns the value, if you use =true it sets the value to true.

Comment: that still wouldn't make sense to me because we want to execute a certain command if it meets a certain criteria. So 
If(box1,2,3 are checked)
{
execute a command
}.
what youre suggesting wouldnt make sense because it doesn't look for a true or false, but actually only checking the status of the box as to whether or not it is checked or not checked.

Comment: Dude you're not getting it, it returns the status. So if box 1 is checked and you say... if (document.getElementById("c1").checked) { this will execute} just try it, it should work.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I might have accidentally caused the code to malfunction. Removing = true did the trick. Now there is actually 1 more problem. Is there a way to re enable my shadow button without having to click the phase 5 button? I will upload a GIF demonstrating my problem. Like lets say after having boxes 1-4 are checked then the shadow button should automatically enable without clicking phase 5 button. https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-b0dc069236.gif .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the shadowFunction() at the end of the fifth button, like this:
funct

```
function phase5Function() {
            document.getElementById("c5").checked=true;
            alert("You have completed Phase 5!");
            shadowFunction();}
```

Comment: So, i did what you asked me to do, but now i have another problem. Please refer to my phase5Function() and shadowFunction(). Basically what it is doing is it is checking boxes 1,2, and 3, but what i really want it to do is to verify that phases 1,2, and 3 are actually checked if i click the first 3 phase buttons.

Comment: then add the call to shadowFunction() to all your "phaseFunction"
I would have merge all those functions to one phaseFunction(num) that get the clicked button number, and using switch on the parameter for deciding what checkbox to check
and at the end of this function call shadowFunction